# Build x86 Word "add in" in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, word-addins

I have an add in for Microsoft Word, if I launch it from Visual Studio it open and run correctly but when I try to build and install the .msi on a 64 bit windows 7 I have a problem.
The installation end fine but when I try to open the add in, Word raise an error because it search for the add in in x64 programs file and not in x86 folder. I want that the add in is installed only in x86 programs file and I have specified as **Target platform** x86 and **defaultLocation** [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName].
What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office, so the most likely cause of this issue is that the user has installed 64-bit Office. That means that it must look in the 64-bit locations because a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit Dll. You're referring to the x86 locations, so I'm assuming that your code is 32-bit.

If you don't want to support 64-bit Office then you'll need to detect when there is a 64-bit Word or Office on the system and stop the installation. If you do want to support 32 and 64-bit Office then build your 32-bit one, and then build another MSI with 64-bit target location, 64-bit code, and 64-bit folders such as ProgramFiles64Folder. Your users install the appropriate one for their Office architecture version.